Issue with Changing Audio Route from Bluetooth to Speaker in ZegoCloud Call
I'm using ZegoCloud for handling voice calls in my app. The call works fine, but when a Bluetooth device is connected, I can't switch the audio route to the speaker. Every time I try to change the audio route from Bluetooth to the speaker, it automatically switches back to Bluetooth after 1-2 seconds.
Here’s the code I’m using to change the audio route:
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
    try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
    
    ZegoExpressEngine.shared().setAudioRouteToSpeaker(true)
} catch {
    print("Failed to set speaker route: \(error)")
}



The above code works fine initially, but whenever I attempt to switch the route from Bluetooth to the speaker, the audio keeps reverting back to Bluetooth automatically after 1-2 seconds. How can I fix this issue so that the audio stays routed to the speaker?
Additional Information:
I am handling calls using Zegocloud SDK.
Using AVAudioSession to manage audio routing.

The Zego documentation indicates they specifically do not support this:

Only switching between the earpiece and the speaker is supported. If it is a Bluetooth headset or a wired headset, it does not support routing to the speaker through this interface.

I expect you will need to discuss a feature request with them. As you've seen, iOS is capable of the routing, but Zego is overriding it. You'll need to ask them to stop.
While not related, you do not need to call overrideOutputAudioPort here, and shouldn't add that unless you want to change the setting dynamically.
